# PHP SoapClient: failed certificate verification

Tags: php, ssl, soap, ssl-certificate, ca

I'm trying to send a soap request to some url. My SOAP options are:

```
array(
    'location' => 'https://some_url/',
    'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
    'trace' => 1,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'connection_timeout' => 60,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => true,
            'verify_peer_name' => true,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'cafile' => 'cacert.crt', // This file really exists, checked that
        ]
    ])
);
```

I get the following error:

```
SoapClient::__doRequest(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01
error:04067072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:padding check failed
error:0D0C5006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:EVP lib
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

So I googled for "block type is not 01", but the results are pretty scarce. One might think that ca cert is wrong, but I fetched it with Chromium's Developer tools (Security tab) when I was on a page representing my url. Just to make sure that it's ok I put it in my browser and that page opens without any security warnings, showing me an XML response.
Putting it in /usr/share/ca-certificates/ had no effect either.

Certificate has pem encoding.

verify_peer set to false is not an option of course.

My php version is 5.5.17-2, the same behaviour is observed on PHP 7.0.21-1 though. OS is Ubuntu 16.04. OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012, the same effect on OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does it work from command line curl?

Comment: Nope, it's run from an application. I use SoapClient class with mentioned options.

Comment: Yes, I get it. I am asking you to check if it works with command line curl using same CA. You have  *fetched it with Chromium's Developer tools*,  which confirms it works, but the distance between php and Chrome is quite big.  `curl` is much closer to SoapClient. It will help to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Hmm, quite interesting! It works from the command line!

Comment: I double checked that cacert that I specified in soap options really exists and can be found by my application code.

Comment: cool, try to set `ssl_method` option of soapclient to match the one used in curl. You may need to `curl -v` to get details. Basically the problem narrowed down to setting correct stream context in php, unless curl uses different version of ssl.

Comment: The only curl tls version option that worked out for me was tls1.2, here is the command: curl https://some_url/ --cacert cacert.crt --tlsv1.2 So I specified 'ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS, but my request still fails. And there is no ssl_method option with specific TLS version. I specified ciphers option in ssl part of stream_context, I tried 'ciphers' => 'TLSv1.2, TLSv1.0, SSLv3'. I just tried it, but frankly speaking I don't understand what it is and if it is connected somehow with my problem. And my request failed as well